# Storing variables through onDestroy() event

Tags: java, android, variables, state, ondestroy

I'm looking for a way to store the state of my variables that may have been changed from there initiation variable (ever by user activating a function or other) **through** the **onDestroy()** event so that if i turn my phone on and off my app hasn't reset the variables.

Comment: It is better to use onSaveInstanceState() for storing state of an Activity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate

Comment: did you mean storing the last value of your variable

Comment: I would recommend onStop at the latest. If the data is crtitical, I would recommend saving it immediately instead of waiting for cleanup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is from android reference: "Note: do not count on onDestroy method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)"

For saving variables you can use as said before SharedPreferences.

Example for using inside activity class:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preference_file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("variable_key", variable);
editor.commit();
```

For method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) just use Bungle argument to save variables

Comment: Lot more definitive that the previous answer, and corrected some of my code.

Comment: My Variable is a Boolean, what do i put in place of putString() or what changes should i make?

Comment: for boolean please use putBoolean(...) method

Comment: Brilliant! and sorry to be a bother but any idea on how to call the editor.commit() in a different activity as i cannot make it static?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `SharedPreferences` feature. It is designed just for this case.
Good sites to read are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), [this](http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). And look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851560/how-to-use-sharedpreferences) question.

Comment: I was trying to get Shared preference to work earlier, it must of just been some bad coding that through me off the trail, but now i know that i'm looking in the right direction, thank-you.