# I want to have a variable that shows on the activity 1, if the next activity 2 have already started

Tags: android

I have a few activities, on the Acivity 1 I set a variable active which is true.

Activity 1 => Activity 2 => come back to Activity 1

```
active=true => active=false => active=false
```

I got:

Activity 1:

```
public boolean active = false;

onCreate() {active = true;}

Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(i);
```

This activity must work in the background.

Activity 2:

```
public boolean active = false;

Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
        intent.putExtra("active", active);
```

then I call method `onBackPressed();`

But when I come back Activity 1 appears and I obtain active = true:

`onResume()` and `onRestart()` here I have:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
active = intent.getBooleanExtra("active", active);
```

When I tried to use 
startActivityforResult() method from Activity 1 it doesn't move to the Activity 2 and it's still true.

May be its because I have a main layout in both activities and contents changes.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089286/1146533) answer could help you. In short: you can use `SharedPreferences` to save any variables for coming back to them later thru any activities.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preference_file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("variable_key", variable);
editor.commit();
```

Additionally, even with [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) you can pass some data.

Comment: I've added the class which extended my application with this variable, what about perfomance?

Comment: @Piotr M. Shared Preferences is using external files for storing data, not variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to store the variable as mentioned in above answer but we can do this without using shared preferences as well.

- Create global variable **active** and assign it to True.
- Use **startActivityforResult**() to swittch between Activity 1 => Activity 2
- on **BackPressed**(), OnActivityResult in Activity1 change the global variable value to false. And due to **startActivityforResult**, Activity1 was in **Pause state** and on coming back to Activity 1 **onResume** will be called which won't replace the Global variable.

Comment: I've added the class which extended my application with this variable.