# when we click on logout the username have to be remember if we check remember without using database

Tags: android

iam using two buttons one is for select another is not selected if i click on select img the username have to be display after logout

android

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/log_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/tickmark"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/remember_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_remember"/>


           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/log_img_unselect"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_remember"
               android:src="@drawable/unselect"
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/remember_margin_right"
               android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_remember"/>
```

Comment: In order to help, please add some code, especially the code behind the buttons you are using.

Comment: to save the state , you need some persistence storage, [SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851560/how-to-use-sharedpreferences) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to keep username, without database. And when you click on logout button, call login screen again and read username from Preferences. An example code below:

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String USERNAME_KEY = "counter";

public static String getUsername(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(USERNAME_KEY, null);
    }

public static void setUserEmailToPreference(Context context, String username) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(USERNAME_KEY, username);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Now you only need to call these methods.
Best regards. Uilton.