# How to create shared preferences to internal storage file for my Android app?

Tags: java, android

How to create shared preferences to internal storage file for my android app?
Please give me a detailed response.

[image: kind of like this]

I want to save the data in the internal storage or the app just by clicking the submit button and also want the data to be used later on.

here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ananaybatra.securityme;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";



    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    Button   mButton;
    EditText mEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
                    }
                });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

here is my content_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.example.ananaybatra.securityme.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/Name" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Phone Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Name"
        android:id="@+id/PhoneNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Emergency Contact Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PhoneNumber"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6"
        android:id="@+id/EmergencyContact" />

    <Button
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Submit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="99dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Email ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EmergencyContact"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EmergencyContact"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/EmergencyContact"
        android:id="@+id/EmailID" />

    <TextView
        android:text="App Coded by Ananay Batra."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851560/how-to-use-sharedpreferences

Comment: 'How to create shared preferences to internal storage file' ??? Sorry i have no idea where you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal for what you really want to do, as for saving an object in Internal Storage.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

jsonObject.put("name", nameValue);
jsonObject.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumberValue);
jsonObject.put("emergencyPhoneNumber", emergencyPhoneNumberValue);
jsonObject.put("email", emailValue);

writeFile(context, String.format("%s/%s", context.getFilesDir(), "File name"), jsonObject.toString());

public static void writeFile(Context context, String filePath, String content) throws IOException {

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath, false);
    writer.write(content);

    writer.close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into it.

Comment: You can mark this answer if this answered your question.