# How to get uid from another activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why is it when i toast it like this it really toasts the current users uid

```
Toast.makeText(this, "" + firebaseUser.getUid(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but when i do it like this

```
databasePassenger.child("Passenger").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                 .addValueEventlistener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     adapter.add(("Name: \t") +dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue());
```

It displays Name: null

Comment: save uid in sharepreference in order to use in another activity

Comment: how can i save uid in sharedpreference sir @HiteshGehlot ? (Sorry im beginner) -

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/3536264

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the `uid` in another activity please use this code.

In the FirstActivity:

```
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the SecondActivity:

```
String uid = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("uid");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: somethings wrong with it, it says.
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soco.itproject.com.hitch_passenger/soco.itproject.com.hitch_passenger.BookingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Your `firebaseUser.getUid();` is different than `null`?

Comment: I haven't solve it yet sir .Maybe its because im not done yet implementing the sharedpreference

Comment: Yes, another approach is to use `SharedPreferences`. Would you like me to send you a post regaring this way of solving the problem?

Comment: Yes sir, please!. Thank you!

Comment: Please take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851560/how-to-use-sharedpreferences). It will learn you how to store and retrieve strings with SharedPreferences.

Comment: this is my line of code `sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("User ID: ",userID);
            editor.commit();

             if (editor != null){

                 System.out.println(editor);
             }`
---------------------------------------------------------------
But it prints `System.out: android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl@202c23b`

Comment: I suggest you iterate on the content of the `SharedPreferences`.